# NGINX cache does not work

Tags: nginx

I am using Debian 8, Nginx 1.10, server Apache2.
My Nginx configuration is:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
server {
....
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|css|js)$ {
       proxy_cache my_zone;
       expires 24h;
       add_header Cache-Control "public";
       proxy_pass http://*******.com;
       proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;
       add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}
```

And the CURL's result is:
`curl -X GET -I http://******/test.png`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Sat, 22 Jul 2017 01:55:56 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 28847
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 06:10:10 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Sun, 23 Jul 2017 01:55:56 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Cache-Control: public
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Are there any missing configurations?

Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: You have two caching headers for Cache-Control, find a way to combine them into one. I just clear then reset the headers:  more_clear_headers "Cache-Control"; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Expires"; add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";

Comment: @Tim The ` Cache-Control` is fine now, but the Cache still misses ;)